# Assigning accessibilitytrait UIAccessibilityTraits.button to other UI Elements in swift

Tags: swift, uiaccessibility

I would like to know whether we can add a different accessibility trait like .button to some other elements other than button like UIVIew/UIImage in swift?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add other traits such as button or link to any element that is not a button or link.
You can do this by setting the accessibility traits of that particular element.
Also, you can have more than one trait on an element.

myView.accessibilityTraits = .button

This helps the user Voiceover user to understand more clearly when we have created a custom view such as a uiview with a pan gesture implemented. We can have a button trait added to the view and the VO user can easily understand the behavior of the view.

Read further here
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilitytraits